# Optimal response payload splitting

Tags: http, browser, https

I have a web application where the response payload is typically an image. The size of this image is variable and can reach up to 1-2 MB in certain cases and this slows down the load time on my clients. I have a way to split this image into N parts and get each of these parts separately and stitch them on the client. This way I can utilize the maximum possible parallel downloads from the browser but I am worried that each of those requests will have additional overhead.

Just want to understand how to best model this? For example if I have an image of X MB, how many parts should it be split into to get optimal load times on the client?

Comment: Why do you think you can actually speed up things that way?

Comment: @JulianReschke I am hoping that parallel downloads combined will get the content faster. For example, I believe getting 3 MB over 6 parallel download channels (512 KB  each) should be faster as compared to getting the entire 3 MB over a single channel. You can correct me if that is not a valid assumption.

Comment: Doesn't look like a sound approach to me either. Could you tell a bit more about the use case? For what purpose are those images downloaded?

Comment: The images basically represent a view of user's content. It is dynamic so can't be served from the CDN. Let's just say it can't be cached in the browser either. I am just trying to understand what should be the best strategy to get all that downloaded.